# Which partition should I choose to install Ubuntu and uninstall Windows 10?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, boot-partition, unetbootin

I'm new to Linux and trying to delete Windows and install Ubuntu.  Here's the partitions image:

[image: Image of partitions]

I used unetbootin to boot from HDD. I don't know which partition to choose.

Comment: Many uninstall Windows but later find one application or game they have to have that does not work in Linux. Best to at least have good backup. Also make sure Windows fast start up is off, or you will not be able to read any NTFS partitions as Windows sets hibernation flag. Looks like older BIOS/MBR install. Usually Windows 10 is UEFI with gpt partitioning?

Comment: If you got UNetbootin Frugal install working I am impressed. With Frugal install you should be able to use "Something else" install mode and install to an empty partition of 50GB or larger. Oldfred gives good advice above.

Answer (score 1):

If you have only one HDD/SSD delete all, go back and select first choice. That'll do partitioning for you.

If you want **hibernate** / **sleep** to function, properly do the following.

- Delete all
- Create 200 MB mount **EFI** OR **Boot+ESP**
- Create another partition with mount **/** and leave the amount of ram you have.
- The last partition set as **swap** in mount.

Also later on, `sudo apt-get gparted` this tool will be your friend in the future when partitioning.

Answer (score 0):

If you are very sure you want to get rid Windows, then a simple choice on install is the 'erase and install' option.  This deletes Windows and all data on hard drive and installs Ubuntu.

To keep Windows for incase option, use sda5 partition, looks to be empty data partition, but check first.  Use the 'something else' option on install.